# Did a hospital employee put up "ebola" signs to cover up he was making fries?

Tags: ebola

[According to the Dutch news site RTV Oost](http://www.rtvoost.nl/nieuws/default.aspx?nid=202775&cat=1), an employee at the hospital Isala Klinieken in Zwolle was making fries in a place where that was not allowed.

In order to not be caught, he put up signs saying "no entry - ebola". The story has been picked up by many, if not all, Dutch news sources. Is the story true?

Comment: You say you don't trust the news sites; what other evidence do you think people could produce? Allegedly i.e. [according to this news](http://www.ad.nl/ad/nl/1012/Nederland/article/detail/3784140/2014/11/06/Medewerker-geschorst-na-frituren-in-operatiekamer.dhtml) the hospital doesn't confirm or deny the events, because of ongoing legal proceedings. So perhaps this is applicable: [Questions about unresolved current events and issues currently under investigation by a court of law, government, or other similar investigative body are off-topic.](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2868/2703)

Comment: @ChrisW I'm not really worried about the news sites making up the whole story. However, all other news sites base their articles on on RTV Oost, which itself relies on a single source for the part of the story that says the employee was suspended for making fries in the complex with the operation rooms and putting up “ebola” signs. That the employee got suspended was confirmed by the hospital, but the reason for doing so was not. Anyway, it looks like the hospital has decided to confirm the story after all, see [this answer by SQB](//skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/23771/11892).

Comment: Yes, I upvoted that answer. Another source of 'evidence' would be if there were civil or criminal proceedings, and if the legal/court papers associated with those proceedings were public/published.

Comment: I'm confused as to how a person "makes fries" in an area where that is not allowed. Why is there a commercial deep fryer in this area to begin with?

Comment: @WakeDemons3 presumably, they brought a consumer-grade deep fryer from home.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the hospital itself, [yes, it did happen](https://web.archive.org/web/20150409055038/http://www.isala.nl/over-isala/nieuws/reactie-berichtgeving-schorsing) (preserved by the *Wayback Machine*; contents in Dutch).

> #### Reactie Isala op berichtgeving over schorsing medewerker
>
> Donderdag 6 november 2014
> ​Er heeft zich binnen Isala een ontoelaatbaar incident voorgedaan dat aanleiding heeft gegeven tot een intern onderzoek.
>
> Het incident betreft het frituren in het OK-complex waarbij briefjes zijn opgehangen met een verwijzing naar Ebola om deze actie te verhullen.
>
> Dit is op geen enkele wijze in overeenstemming met de normen en waarden van Isala.  Daarom neemt Isala dit zeer hoog op en zijn er maatregelen genomen die hebben geleid tot een schorsing van een medewerker. Bij drie andere betrokken medewerkers is een aantekening in hun dossier gemaakt.
>
> We willen graag benadrukken dat de patiëntveiligheid niet in het geding is geweest.  Nadat het incident zich heeft voorgedaan is de betreffende ruimte in het OK-complex volledig gereinigd, voordat er weer operaties hebben plaatsgevonden.

Translation (mine):

> #### Reaction by Isala to news about suspension employee
>
> Thursday, November 6, 2014
> An unacceptable incident has occurred within Isala that has led to an internal investigation.
>
> The incident concerns frying in the OR complex while putting up notes referencing Ebola to conceal this action.
>
> This is in no way in accordance with the standards and values of Isala. Therefore Isala has taken this very seriously and has taken measures that have led to suspension of an employee. Three other employees involved have received a note on their records.
>
> We would like to emphasize that patient safety has not been compromised. After the incident occurred, the room involved was cleaned thoroughly before another surgery took place.